# sentential modifiers(?) and relative clause question

Tags: particles, syntax, relative-clauses

I just finished Japanese level 2 in college, which as I have come to understand is ~the most important~ and I came away with quite a lot of questions.

We learned about relative clauses and something my teacher referred to as a "sentential modifier" and they seem very similar, but clearly have different functions. Hoping someone could help.

> コーヒーを飲んでいる男の人です。
>
> the man drinking coffee

So as I understand this is an example of a relative clause (i.e. the preceding clause modifies the noun).
However, when my sensei brought up a "sentential modifier" she kind of glossed over it. But here was the sentence

> これは私が使う水です。
>
> That is the water I use.

So, these things are pretty similar, but I was hoping someone could clarify this for me.  Both sentences use the short form of verbs and no particle between the verb and the ~leading~ noun.

If these are both correct, how commonly are clauses/sentences like this used? Are there any "rules" about use of particles in these instances?

Comment: By "short form" do you mean "verb form without 〜ます"?  I think the usual term for "leading noun" is "head noun".

Comment: Sounds like they're just 2 names for the same thing. If you're asking why one has ～でいる, while the other has ～う, that's a bit more complicated to explain.

Comment: yes. i should have said dictionary form, but i always think of that as "the shortest form" 

and yes, as i was writing this out i was curious as to why the first sentence took to the present progressive, and the second sentence remained more general.

any information on this would be excellent!
私がここで習いまよ！

Answer (score 1):

- S1. 　コーヒーを飲んでいる男の人です。 == Here's a man (who is) drinking coffee.  ( a relative clause  ? )
- S2. 　これは私が使う水です。 == This is the water [that I use].

The latter is said to contain a  "sentential modifier" because instead of 
[that I use], it could be [that Peter uses] or (based on) any elaborate sentence.

e.g. 　「これは、頭が赤い魚を食べた猫と私が飲む水です。」

I think the main difference is whether the [relative clause] contains a subject or not -- (I mean "subject" in the sense of English grammar.)

Comment: (If I get enough points, I'll continue.) <- enough for what?

Comment: (If I get enough [reputation] points, I'll continue.)

Comment: Why do you need to get more reputation to continue writing and complete your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand your question exactly but I try to answer.

If a sentence or a phrase modifies a noun, a postpositional particle isn't necessary like コーヒーを飲んでいる男, 私が使う水.

If a noun or noun phrase modifies a noun, a postpositional particle の is necessary like 男の人, 図書館の本, 大きく成功した会社の社長.

Answer (score 0):

I can't (at least instantly) think of any relative clause which use special particle to connect to the noun.

So I suppose answer is:

- They are both commonly used grammer
- No.  There is no Japanese grammer which use special (or, dedicated...?) particle to connect a relative clause to a noun.